# Drawing a double arrow line

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to render a double sided arrow using the `Geometry` class. I've been able to get an arrow as below image:

[image]

As you can see from the image, it seems that the line is off as well on the bottom right where it's highlighted in yellow:

[image]

I am trying to achieve drawing a double sided arrow line like the image below:

[image]

Here's what I am working with so far, if more details need to be added please let me know.

```
public class DoubleArrow : Shape
{
   public DoubleArrow() : base()
   {
      Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
   }

   protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
   {
      get { return GetGeometry(); }
   }

   protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   {
      return constraint;
   }

   private Geometry GetGeometry()
   {                     
      return Geometry.Parse("M 0 4 L 16 4 L 10 0 M 16 4 L 10 8");
   }
}
```

Comment: Set StrokeStartLineCap, StrokeEndLineCap and StrokeLineJoin to `Round`.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, the answer below and your suggestion worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing your path like a stroke:

[image: Original SVG path]

This will not allow you to use `Fill` and is the reason your point looks mismatched. If you instead draw your path like a polygon, you will be able to use `Fill` and your points will appear aligned.

[image: New SVG path]

Here's the path I would use, you can check it out using [this online editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).

```
M 0  4
L 4  2
L 4  3.75
L 16 3.75
L 16 2
L 20 4
L 16 6
L 16 4.25
L 4  4.25
L 4  6
L 0  4
```

**Edit**

Just saw that you changed your target picture. Here's the path I would use for the new one:

```
M 4  2
L 0  4
L 4  6
M 0  4
L 20 4
M 16 2
L 20 4
L 16 6
```

[image: Stroke SVG path]